# JavaScript code modification for GA time tracker

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

```
// Copyright 2007 Google, Inc.
// This sample code is under the Apache2 license, see
// http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 for license details.
/**
 * @fileoverview Wrapper for Time Tracking
 */

/**
 * @class Time Tracking component.
 *     This class encapsulates all logic for time tracking on a particular
 *     page. Time tracking could be for any object within a page or the page
 *     itself.
 *
 * @param {Array.<Number>} arg1 Optional array that represents the bucket
 * @constructor
 */
var TimeTracker = function(opt_bucket) {
  if (opt_bucket) {
    this.bucket_ = opt_bucket.sort(this.sortNumber); 
  } else {
    this.bucket_ = TimeTracker.DEFAULT_BUCKET;
  }
};

TimeTracker.prototype.startTime_;
TimeTracker.prototype.stopTime_;
TimeTracker.prototype.bucket_;
TimeTracker.DEFAULT_BUCKET = [100, 500, 1500, 2500, 5000];

/**
 * Calculates time difference between start and stop
 * @return {Number} The time difference between start and stop
 */
TimeTracker.prototype._getTimeDiff = function() {
  return (this.stopTime_ - this.startTime_);
};

/**
 * Helper function to sort an Array of numbers
 * @param {Number} arg1 The first number
 * @param {Number} arg2 The second number
 * @return {Number} The difference used to sort
 */
TimeTracker.prototype.sortNumber = function(a, b) {
  return (a - b);
}

/**
 * Records the start time
 * @param {Number} arg1 Optional start time specified by user
 */
TimeTracker.prototype._recordStartTime = function(opt_time) {
  if (opt_time != undefined) {
    this.startTime_ = opt_time;
  } else {
    this.startTime_ = (new Date()).getTime();
  }
};

/**
 * Records the stop time
 * @param {Number} arg1 Optional stop time specified by user
 */
TimeTracker.prototype._recordEndTime = function(opt_time) {
  if (opt_time != undefined) {
    this.stopTime_ = opt_time;
  } else {
    this.stopTime_ = (new Date()).getTime();
  }
};

/**
 * Tracks the event. Calculates time and sends information to
 * the event tracker passed
 * @param {Object} arg1 GA tracker created by user
 * @param {String} arg2 Optional event object name
 * @param {String} arg3 Optional event label
 */
TimeTracker.prototype._track = function(tracker,
                                        opt_event_obj_name,
                                        opt_event_label) {
  var eventTracker;
  if (opt_event_obj_name != undefined && opt_event_obj_name.length != 0) {
    eventTracker = tracker._createEventTracker(opt_event_obj_name);
  } else {
    eventTracker = tracker._createEventTracker('TimeTracker');
  }

  var i;
  var bucketString;
  for(i = 0; i < this.bucket_.length; i++) {
    if ((this._getTimeDiff()) < this.bucket_[i]) {
      if (i == 0) {
        bucketString = "0-" + (this.bucket_[0]);
        break;
      } else {
        bucketString = this.bucket_[i - 1] + "-" + (this.bucket_[i] - 1);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (!bucketString) {
    bucketString = this.bucket_[i - 1] + "+";
  }
  eventTracker._trackEvent(bucketString, opt_event_label, this._getTimeDiff());
};

/**
 * Sets the bucket for histogram generation in GA
 * @param {Array.<Number>} The bucket array
 */
TimeTracker.prototype._setHistogramBuckets = function(buckets_array) {
  this.bucket_ = buckets_array.sort(this.sortNumber);
};
```

I want to remove any functionality related to  bucket time
and use  additional parameter opt_event_obj_nameAction to pass the value as action to Google Analytic. I tried and cannot get it work. need some help?

look here http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerWrappers.html

```
TimeTracker.prototype._track = function (tracker,
                                        opt_event_obj_name, opt_event_obj_nameAction,
                                        opt_event_label) {
    var eventTracker;
    var eventTrackerAction;
    eventTrackerAction = tracker._createEventTracker(opt_event_obj_nameAction)
    if (opt_event_obj_name != undefined && opt_event_obj_name.length != 0) {
        eventTracker = tracker._createEventTracker(opt_event_obj_name);

    } else {
        eventTracker = tracker._createEventTracker('TimeTracker');

    }
```

Comment: What exactly did you try?  In what way did it not work?

Comment: I added additional parameter to TimeTracker.prototype._track = function() so that i can pass the value as action to GA report but time buckets are show as action